# Get Sum of every other column except for the first two ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have currently a table of areas of NY city, age and population over the year and projected population in the future in .csv like this:

| Area | Age | 2021 | 2022 | Other year until 2034 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manhattan, NY | 0 | 38401 | 38521 | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | 1 | 38738 | 30188 | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | .. | ..... | ..... | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | 85+ | ..... | ..... | ...................... |
| Brooklyn, NY | 0 | ..... | ..... | ...................... |

I want to group this based on the areas and the age group and sum up each of the other columns so in the end it is like this:

| Area | Age | 2021 | 2022 | Other year until 2034 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manhattan, NY | 0-4 | 180129 | 190309 | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | 5-9 | 302109 | 201890 | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | .. | ..... | ..... | ...................... |
| Manhattan, NY | 85+ | ..... | ..... | ...................... |
| Brooklyn, NY | 0-4 | ..... | ..... | ...................... |

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This looks like you have a denormalise design; having one column for each year does *not* scale.

Comment: It's true it's denormalized. But it's how the US Census Bureau  and other agencies deliver their data. Using that data, we're either stuck with it or must reorganize it to be normalized.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not there is need to normalize. Currently I want to load this into a Power BI report and make a map out of the projection, i.e user choose a filter age 0-5 and year 2024 then I will show that "The projected growth of age group 0-5 in year 2024 compared to 2021 is 3% in Brooklyn" . Please advice if there is need to normalize in this case.

Comment: Unless it is a one-time thing, which apparently it is not, you should normalize your table.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify how the age ranges are defined.  One method is a giant `case` expression.  But `values()` may be simpler to maintain:

```
select t.area, v.range,
       sum([2020]) as [2020], sum([2021]) as [2021], . . . 
from t join
     (value ('0-4', 0, 4),
            ('5-9', 5, 9),
            . . . 
            ('85+', 85, null)
     ) v(range, lo, hi)
     on t.age >= v.lo and (t.age < v.hi or v.hi is null)
group by t.area, v.range;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for your response. I have no problem to do the giant case expression, my problem mainly is the year. I do not want to rewrite the same sql over the year when the new year numbers are added. This year they have information from 2020- 2034 released in one .csv file but next year it could be 2021-2035, so essentially I want not to hard code the column as sum([2020]) but more like sum of the column header that can be found i.e. sum([column header 1]).

Comment: @hhp . . . SQL does not deal very well with variable numbers of columns.  I would suggest that you restructure the data so each row has only one year (and year is a column).  In any case, this answers the question that you asked here.